# If remainingSlot = 0 then remove/hide a specific item in the combobox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the variable remainingSlot is in javascript and and i want to use it in my jquery, if remainingSlot == 0, then remove/hide the item from the combobox. im really having a problem about this and i'm still new to html please need help thanks in advance (sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
if(remainingSlot == 0){
document.getElementById('id_here').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Jquery**

```
if(remainingSlot == 0){
$('#id_here').hide();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! People here are so helpful.

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui  Please mark it as answer, If you found helpful.

Comment: I don't know this is my first time to ask a question here @MoeedFarooqui